# How to separate a list with no commas into a list with commas

Tags: python, list

I have a list that's just one string with 5 words.
I want to be able to separate the string by using commas so it will end up with a list that has 5 strings. How am I able to do this?

tried a for loop to replace `\` with `"` but for some reason it didn't work.

```
list=['order_id\tquantity\titem_name\tchoice_description\titem_price']
```

how do i separate it so that it becomes

```
list=['order_id','quantity','item_name','choice_description','item_price']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 1):

This should split your string into a list.

`list = list[0].split("\t")`

Comment: `list = list[0].split("\t")`. The string is already a list element

Comment: Changed my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() on that original string in that list which you wish to split and store separate strings in a list.

eg. 
"your string".split("\t")

**First Edit:**
Splitting your string with space will given you a tuple of 5 separate strings which your can now store in a list or keep appending to a new list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function .

```
list = 'order_id\tquantity\titem_name\tchoice_description\titem_price'.split('\t')
```

**Edit**: You can acces the first element on the original list by doing list[0]. So your code should be:

```
l = ['order_id\tquantity\titem_name\tchoice_description\titem_price']
l = l[0].split('\t')
```